# There exists an $f:A \rightarrow B$ that is $1-1$ if and only if $|A| \leq |B|$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

There exists an $f:A \rightarrow B$ that is $1-1$ if and only if $|A| \leq |B|$

Proof:

($\Rightarrow$) Since $A \sim f(A) \subseteq B$, $|A| \leq |B|$

($\Leftarrow$) Let $|A| \sim |C|$ where $C \subseteq B$

$g:A \rightarrow C$, $h:C \rightarrow B$

Claim : $g \circ h:A \rightarrow B$ : $1-1$

Is this proof true? and i don't know how can poorf goh  is injection

Comment: Your proof is correct, if by $\text{card} B\le \text{card} C$ you mean there is $C\subset B$ and a bijective map $g:A \to C$.

Comment: It looks rather incomplete but the idea seems to be right...isn't this *exactly* the definition of $\;|A|\le |B|\;$ , anyway?

Comment: What your definition of $|A|\leq |B|$? I'd say the definition is exactly what you want to prove, as mentioned in the above comment. There really isn't anything to prove.

Comment: Try to prove that composition of injective functions is injective.